# Composer detected issues in Server

Tags: php, mysql, server, localhost, phpmailer

I created the registration form for the website and used phpmailer for sending mail. Pages are running without ang error on the local host and the user sends a verification link to their mail. However, when I load the page to the server and prform the register, I get the following error.

Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.0".

I checked the versions. I am using php version 8.0.10. How can I resolve this error?

composer.json

```
{
    "require" : {
        "psr/log" : "dev-master",
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.5"
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your webserver is running >= 8.0.0? If so, can you show us your webserver config, if you're using apache or nginx, for example.

Comment: @steadweb I connect the webserver remotely so I think I can not show the server config. The university's IT department provided me with a server.

Comment: You might be running different versions of PHP for command line and web, or the web server may be configured with multiple PHP versions. Double check the version *in the same context your script runs in*.